# Swift NSPredicate NOT IN

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have an array of X number of items and I need to filter out specific items by uid. I've written the following predicate, which I believe to be correct. The problem I'm facing is that the Swift compiler is only allowing me to use the initialiser which accepts argumentArray.

```
let uids = ["34885a9f0897f8e9", "11364aca04e29be0", "c25047b10ad2a0d2"]
NSPredicate(format: "NOT (uid IN %@)", argumentArray: uids)
```

Which always resolves to the following:

```
NOT uid IN "18bbfd4d3f099297"
```

I know I'm missing something obvious here. How can I construct an NSPredicate to filter an array of 25 items down to an array of 22 items which does not include the `uids` listed above? I need to pass this predicate into some Objective-C code.

Comment: can you cast `uids` to NSArray explicitly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't use `NSPredicate(format:argumentArray:)`. The second parameter is provided to pass an array of arguments to replace multiple placeholder tokens in the format string.

Just pass `uids` as the replacement for `%@`

```
NSPredicate(format: "NOT (uid IN %@)", uids)
```

Comment: Thank u very much, for the answer, it helped me a lot