# Swift/Core Data: how to get items not joined in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I am really new to Core Data and struggling a little. I have three entities: Person, Emoji, and PersonEmoji. There are a list of Emoji's and a Person can have  a number of them (PersonEmoji), each with a number of points (person 1 has a heart emoji with 3 out of 5 points). I am trying to get a list of the Emoji's a Person doesn't yet have. The PersonEmoji has two fields personid and emojiid mapped to each entity (many to many).

I asked chat gpt this question:

> Can you show me what a many to many join @FetchRequest looks like in
> Swift with a NSPredecate

and got back:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "ANY entities IN %@", argumentArray: [entities]))
var items: FetchedResults<Item>
```

and I figure I need to replace the item with my objects:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Emoji.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "ANY emojiid IN %@", argumentArray: [emojis]))
var items: FetchedResults<Emoji>
```

When I try this I get:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I think I'm pretty far off from the solution. I need to pass the person id into the view as well so the person is constrained as well. If the emoji gets selected from the "not in" list I want it added to the PersonEmoji entity and removed from the list.

**UPDATE**

I saw this [NOT IN post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878138/swift-nspredicate-not-in#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20use%20NSPredicate%20%28format%3AargumentArray%3A%29.%20The%20second%20parameter%20is,%25%40%20NSPredicate%20%28format%3A%20%22NOT%20%28uid%20IN%20%25%40%29%22%2C%20uids%29) which seemed like a good option (Emoji NOT IN...and then the Person.personEmoji, but I am struggling to get it to work.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973660/coredata-many-to-many-relationship) as well, with a similar case (Recipe -> IngredientInfo -> Ingredient) where there is a count attribute on the IngredientInfo intermediate table requiring the intermediate table to be created manually. It stated:

> Or to quick access to all ingredients in certain Recipe use KVC

using:

```
NSSet* ingredients = [recipe valueForKeyPath:@"ingredientInfo.ingredient"];
```

but I think this isn't a Swift solution.

I essentially need to get an array of emoji.id from the person object. I extended the Person class to get an array of PersonEmoji's and would like to add one to get an array of Emoji.id, so I can pass it to the NOT IN statement, but cannot figure out how to do it.

```
extension Person {
    
    public var wrappedName : String {
        name ?? "Unknown Person name"
    }
    
    public var personEmojiArray: [PersonEmoji] {
        let set = personEmoji as? Set<PersonEmoji> ?? []
        
        return set.sorted {
            $0.rating < $1.rating
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Change `var items: FetchedResults<Token>` to `var items: FetchedResults<Emoji>`. And, while you are at it, use better names, like `var emojis: FetchedResults<Token>` so you know what the variable contains.

Comment: I changed the Token to Emoji (token was another core data entity which I put in the wrong place).

Comment: something like `parent == nil`

Comment: Core Data is not an sql database so you don’t need the PersonEmoji entity, instead create a many-to-many relationship between Person and Emoji.

Comment: What if I wanted to store a points value for each emoji associated with a person. Wouldn't I need a PersonEmoji entity for that?

Comment: Yes if you have additional attributes then you need it but that is a completely different scenario than what you described in your question.

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution is to load the PersonEmoji objects for a person and all Emoji objects in two separate fetch requests and then use a Set to get all unused Emoji objects.

Comment: Sorry, @JoakimDanielson. I should have made mention of the additional attributes instead of glossing over them and going directly to the many-to-many structure. I have updated the post to include the additional attribute in the association.

Answer (score 0):

I understand `PersonEmoji` is a an intermediate (join) entity, covered in the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW8).

Your fetch declaration needs a few things removed and a sort descriptor added:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)])
var items: FetchedResults<Emoji>

let person: Person // or @ObservedObject var person: Person if you are using it's properties in this View.
```

Then in your `body` you can try:

```
var body: some View {
    let _ = items.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "NONE personEmoji.person == %@", person)
    ForEach(items) { item in
```

I know it's non-standard to set things in body but fortunately its non-mutating.

Comment: But what if I wanted to store a points associated with the PersonEmoji?

Comment: Sorry didn't realise, it is possible to make a manual pivot table. I added a predicate you could try.

Comment: `"NONE personEmoji.person == %@"`

Comment: Hmm. Not seeing any Emoji's in the sheet. I must be doing something wrong. It's running. In the Person detail form I need to list the associated Emojis to see if any are there. I'm struggling with Core Data a little.

Comment: In SQL I would do a NOT IN with a subquery for all those in the personEmoji for that Person, or a LEFT JOIN of personEmoji against emoji where the join value was null.